# Trying to import a python module that is installed receiving error

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, pythonpath

I'm new to python so this might be a simple fix but I couldn't find a solution by just googling. I'm getting this error when trying to run an import on a module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/joeshmo/OneDrive - company Industries/Documents/Python/Excel Join/join.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Openpyxl is already installed as pip gives me this...

```
pip install openpyxl    
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\users\joeshmo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in c:\users\joeshmo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\joeshmo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.0.1)
```

Python installed here...

```
C:\Users\joeshmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
```

PythonPath here...

```
C:\Users\joeshmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python38.zip
C:\Users\joeshmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\DLLs
C:\Users\joeshmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib
C:\Users\joeshmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
C:\Users\joeshmo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages
C:\Users\joeshmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
```

On windows 10.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: do you use virtual env?

Comment: Make sure you're running your python script with python3.8. Otherwise, try installing with `pip3`. The package manager and the python version must match

Comment: @stilManiac - no, just on my machine.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman - How do i verify that? I've only ever installed this one version. (new to python) :D

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: Using vscode, what specifically do you mean by 'it'?

Comment: I meant run the code. You probably have to make sure that vscode runs the correct python version. There should be a configuration file somewhere that specifies it. Try running python from the command line once with `py --version` (I think that's the syntax, don't use windows). If it shows version 3.8, try running your code with `py "c:/Users/joeshmo/OneDrive - company Industries/Documents/Python/Excel Join/join.py"`

Comment: Yes, it's running 3.8. Ran as you suggested as well, same error code. @TedKleinBergman

Comment: That's really odd. Only thing I can think of is that you might have duplicate python executables or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubleshooting with a colleague, we discovered I had 2 versions of python running. I could run "py" (3.8.0) or "python"(3.8.5). After uninstalling the older version. This was no longer an issue.